# CiviCRM Groups Sync Plugin for Wordpress - No access to Settings

Tags: wordpress

I installed the CiviCRM Groups Sync Plugin after finding the CiviCRM Member Sync plugin is not currently syncing to the WP Groups.

It was all working and I set up a 'Guests' group in CiviCRM to sync to WP and it created the group 'Guests' in Wordpress. So that worked.

However, I registered as a Guest user via CiviCRM profile (which includes a create WP user account form) and was added to the Civi Guests group but not the WP Guests group.

I was just added to the default 'Registered' Group.

And now I've discovered I cannot access the CiviCRM Groups Sync plugin's Settings page. I get the dreaded '**Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.**'

This is the page being accessed https://somesite.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm_groups_sync_parent

I'm logged into WP as Administrator.

I'm not seeing any errors in the PHP error log, and have WP DEBUG on but not showing any errors.

Help!

Cheers,
Tracy

UPDATE:
[image: Link to Group Sync Settings]

UPDATE: Also, this plugin does not really help with removing the user when their Civi Membership lapses. So really the member sync plugin would be ideal as it works with the differing Civi Membership states.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone else is wondering, the Settings link in the plugin (shown in the screenshot in my original question) is an unused link (at the present).

I will post a separate question on why the Groups sync plugin is only syncing when a contact gets manually added to a Civi Group.

Answer (score 4):

> I registered as a Guest user via CiviCRM profile (which includes a create WP user account form) and ... [snip] ... now I've discovered I cannot access the CiviCRM Groups Sync plugin's Settings page

I can't be entirely sure, but I think you may have been confused by the process of registering "as a Guest user via CiviCRM profile". When you do this and create a user account at the same time, CiviCRM will *automatically log you in as that user*. (FWIW that's one reason I don't use this functionality since there's no way to prevent that from happening) If you subsequently browse your WordPress site *as that user*, you'll find (depending on the default user role you have set) that you cannot access parts of it. You'd need to log out of WordPress and log in as your admin user to restore your capabilities.

> Also, this plugin does not really help with removing the user when their Civi Membership lapses. So really the member sync plugin would be ideal as it works with the differing Civi Membership states.

As I said in response to another question of yours on SE, this is on my to-do list. Please be patient and remember that the joy of free software is that it's free. My time, on the other hand, is limited - especially in the summer holidays. Luckily for you, funding has indeed been found and set aside to implement this - when I have the time to do so!

Comment: Hi Christian, I'm logged in as Admin when the settings aren't showing. Another Admin user is also locked out of the Settings. No other plugins are having any permission problems and I'm not seeing any settings in Civi that would stop it. Could it be something in the .htaccess file stopping the Settings from displaying? My comment re the Membership plugin was there to show other readers that I knew about that the plugin, sorry if it came over as a poke. It has been suggested I use Civi Smart Groups to sync with WP so that fixes my issue with CiviMembers syncing with WP.

Comment: Would the issue with the Settings not displaying cause the sync not to work? When I signed up using the 'Guest' profile I was added to the Civi 'Guests' group but not the WP Guests group, even though this was created when I created the group in Civi and ticked the Groups Sync box. I was just added to the default 'Registered' Group. Is it worth me deactivating and deleting the plugin and starting again?

Comment: FYI I am getting 'There is an existing CiviCRM group that is linked to this group. The group members will exist in both groups.' when I go to Edit the WP Group 'Guests'. I added an existing Civi contact/WP User to the Guests group in Civi and it added them to the WP Guests group. So the plugin is definitely syncing between the groups. I will sign up another test user on the Guest profile and see if that works now---maybe I missed something on the first time around.

Comment: @BizHarbour I'm not quite sure how you got the URL, but there is no CiviCRM Groups Sync "Settings" page. There's placeholder code, admittedly, but it's disabled.

Comment: Hi Christian, I'm getting to that page by clicking on Settings under the plugin name in the WP Plugins dashboard.I'll relax if there are no settings there :) However, the plugin is definitely not syncing Civi contacts who sign up using the Civi profile. They are added to the Guest group in Civi but it is not syncing with the Guest group in WP. The WP user is created when the profile is filled out, and they are being added to the default 'Registered' group. The Guest groups are definitely syncing when I manually add a contact to the Guest group in Civi. Should there be a scheduled job?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my original question showing the Settings link I'm referring to.

Comment: Ah, that Settings link is an oversight. Please ignore!

Comment: I wonder if the Contact is added to the CiviCRM group before or after the WordPress user is created... hmm... I'll look into it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the overall Wordpress permissions for Civi and make sure the permissions are correct. I would also check to see if APIv4 extension is installed. I'm finding a couple of Civi extensions do not function if APIv4 is active.

Comment: Hi, I've checked the WP permissions for Civi and it doesn't have a row for Admin (only Anonymous, Subscriber, Contributor, Author, Editor). It says 'Super Admin and Administrator roles will have all permissions in CiviCRM.' Is there somewhere else to change permissions? Also this is a Wordpress plugin as opposed to a Civi Extension

Answer (score 0):

`Also, this plugin does not really help with removing the user when their Civi Membership lapses. So really the member sync plugin would be ideal as it works with the differing Civi Membership states.`

If you use the Members plugin alongside Christian Wach's CiviCRM Wordpress Member Sync - you could achieve what you are trying to achieve.